# Deprecate sizeWithFont: UIFont constrainedToSize:CGSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakMode in MBProgressHud

Tags: ios, mbprogresshud

In my app I'm using the [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD), but when I try to run my app it shows me that the method:

`sizeWithFont:(UIFont *) forWidth:(CGFloat) lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)`

it's deprecated and it suggest me to use this method:

`boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize) options:(NSStringDrawingOptions) attributes:(NSDictionary *) context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)`

but how I can use this method in this library? The method it's in the `MBProgressHUD.m`. There's a simple solution to silence this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just download the latest version? This has been fixed as of commit [a50f7a3](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD/commit/a50f7a36a4d4e37fc804aa50b17f0a3163d92957).